# How can I get the position of an mkannotation while it is being dragged

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkannotation

How can I get the coordinates of an MKAnnotation while it is being dragged? I don't see anything in the Apple documentation that would make it easy.

Comment: Here asking co-ordinate means Latitude and longitude or actual x and y on screen?

Comment: I am asking for latitude and longitude. What I am trying to do is have a line follow a annotation while I drag it.

Comment: search more about MKCoordinateForMapPoint...that might help you

Comment: I see what it does, but the reason I asked is because I want to able to move a polyline without having to remove it and then re-add it. Currently it only does this when I drop a the annotation. I need the line to dynamically change while I am dragging the annotation that is connected to it.

Comment: Sorry OP, I won't be able to help for that...Wait until other's answer. Post some pictures to illustrate your problem that will help us to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve

Comment: It's hard to show with pictures. But I guess I can wait.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a polyline as Overlay - there is no other way as to re-add each time it changes. BUT, as you move a ping along the map, it's position and scale can't be changed, so at this point you can just add a regular view on top of the whole map's view. And when you stop moving ping - replace you fake view with corresponding overlay.
Hope, it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved it by creating a uiview with a custom drawRect that drew the lines based on the points I got from the Mapkit.

Comment: Can you share your solution with me? I'm trying to do something very similar! Thanks